# Save Current State of Rails App...Reload if making any undesired changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, save

Hey guys..this is kind of a weird question but I'm making a webapp in rails and I have about half the functionality I'd like to see completed.  Now I've been here before but due to misnaming some model and controllers everything went haywire so I just restarted the app since I knew I already did.

I'm wondering if I can "save game" where I'm at now and continue on...so if mess up in the future I can revert back to a working 1/2 way version of my app.

I just want to save everything how it is and if I mess something up in future I could just go back to where I am now.....Is there any way to do this?  I've been looking and freezing? or versioning? but I'm not sure it is i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called version control and by looking at your tags I think you already know that.

There are many options for version control, but the one right now the most popular for rails developers is called git.

There's a lot of stuff out there to learn about git, but my favourite website is called [gitready](http://gitready.com/).  You should read up on branching, which is a great way to work on experimental features without messing up your application, and tags, which are used to mark a point in time which you can always go back to.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, Thanks Alot.....this really helps...Everyday I learn more about RoR and it just keeps getting better

Comment: Version control will change the way you program.  You can start a "branch" to try something out.  If you don't like it, just move back to your main line of development ('trunk' in svn or 'master' in git) and try something else on a new branch.  It frees you from "ooh, how am I going to back this out if I don't like it?"

Answer (score 1):

just use git or subversion :)